# Finding which is selected without Javascript radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Codepen https://codepen.io/mehmetmasa-the-selector/pen/RwBQbOr

[image]

When I click the button, I add a new field. One of the added fields (radio button) needs to be selected. But since the user can add/delete, I can't give the value value.

HTML Code

```
    <div id="answer">
      <div class="form-group d-flex">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input trueAnswer" type="radio" name="trueAnswer">Doğru Cevap </label>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control answer" type="text" placeholder="Cevabı Yazınız">
        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-3 col-md-1" type="button" id="addAnswer">Yeni Cevap</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS Code

```
    $('#addAnswer').on('click', function() {
        $('<div class="form-group d-flex">' +
            '<div class="form-check">' +
            '<label class="form-check-label">' +
            '<input class="form-check-input trueAnswer" type="radio" name="trueAnswer">Doğru Cevap' +
            '</label>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<input class="form-control answer" type="text" placeholder="Cevabı Yazınız">' +
            '<button class="btn btn-danger ml-3 col-md-1 deleteAnswer" type="button" >Cevabı Sil</button>' +
            '</div>').appendTo('#answer');
    });
```

```
    $('#addQuestion').on('click', function() {
                let answer = [];
                $('#answer .form-group').map(function(i, val) {
                    if ($(val).find('.answer').val().length > 0)
                        answer.push({
                            name: $(val).find('.answer').val(),
                            trueAnswer: $(val).find('.trueAnswer').val()
                        });
                });

                let categoryID = $('#category').val();
                let question = $('#question').val();
                let questionNo = $('#questionNo').val();
                let colorpicker = $('#colorpicker').val();

                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("categoryID", categoryID);
                formData.append("question", question);
                formData.append("questionNo", questionNo);
                formData.append("colorpicker", colorpicker);

                for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
                    formData.append('answer' + [i], answer[i].name);
                    formData.append('answer' + [i], answer[i].trueAnswer);
                }
```

How can I find which answer the user chose?

Comment: function selectAnswer() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          $('#answer div:last').find('input').attr('checked', true);
        }, 300);
      }
you can make a function and call at the end of '</div>').appendTo('#answer');
          selectAnswer(). here

Comment: Also in delete you can add same function